# Getting problem in flatlist of react native

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I am calling an API and in which and rendering its data in flatlist but my flatlist is displaying data by every alphabat seprately. It should be a complete string.

```
    export default class LiveStream extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      videodata: [],
    };
  }

  componentDidMount(search) {
    axios
      .get(
        `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&channelId=UCMmpLL2ucRHAXbNHiCPyIyg&eventType=live&type=video&key=AIzaSyC59vOHzSFtEgvNbJORgf4hI97Is3nnsfI`,
      )
      .then((res) => {
        // console.log(res.data.items[0].id.videoId);

        this.setState({
          videodata: res.data.items[0].id.videoId,
        });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log('Data not loaded');
      });
  }
  render() {
    console.log(this.state.videodata);
    const {videodata} = this.state;
    return (

        <FlatList
          data={videodata}
          renderItem={({item}) => {
            console.log(item);
            return (
              <View style={{justifyContent: 'center', flex: 1}}>
                <YouTube
                  videoId={item.concat('')}
                  play={true}
                  style={{height: 300, bottom: 20}}
                  apiKey={'AIzaSyC59vOHzSFtEgvNbJORgf4hI97Is3nnsfI'}
                />
              </View>
            );
          }}
        />
  }
}
```

In console.log I am getting [image]

Comment: But `videoData` in your `state` object is just a string ... and when you pass it to your `FlatList` ... it will treated as an array of characters ... which exactly what you got up here

Comment: Ahh pls..can u edit my code...i will be so thankful to u..I am really stuck here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Unnecessary use of FlatList` as you are rendering single item inside also your array converted into an array of characters that's why you are seeing single character in the console.
You only need `id` so you can only get the id from response and store in the state. 
I have done a few changes into your code I hope it will work for you.

```
  export default class LiveStream extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      videodata: null,
    };
  }

  componentDidMount(search) {
    axios
      .get(
        `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&channelId=UCMmpLL2ucRHAXbNHiCPyIyg&eventType=live&type=video&key=AIzaSyC59vOHzSFtEgvNbJORgf4hI97Is3nnsfI`,
      )
      .then((res) => {
        // console.log(res.data.items[0].id.videoId);

        this.setState({
          videodata: res.data.items[0].id.videoId,
        });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log('Data not loaded');
      });
  }
  render() {
    console.log(this.state.videodata);
    const {videodata} = this.state;
    return (
              <View style={{justifyContent: 'center', flex: 1}}>
                 { this.state.videodata !== null &&
                <YouTube
                  videoId={item.concat('')}
                  play={true}
                  style={{height: 300, bottom: 20}}
                  apiKey={'AIzaSyC59vOHzSFtEgvNbJORgf4hI97Is3nnsfI'}
                />
                }
              </View>
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

change

```
 this.setState({
          videodata: res.data.items[0].id.videoId,
        });
```

to

```
this.setState({
          videodata: res.data.items,
        });
```

change

```
<FlatList
          data={videodata}
          renderItem={({item}) => {
            console.log(item);
            return (
              <View style={{justifyContent: 'center', flex: 1}}>
                <YouTube
                  videoId={item.concat('')}
```

to

```
<FlatList
          data={videodata}
          renderItem={({item}) => {
            console.log(item);
            return (
              <View style={{justifyContent: 'center', flex: 1}}>
                <YouTube
                  videoId={item.id.videoId}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: It also might be true...but i just set my state to null and then put condition  {this.state.videodata !== null && (
            <YouTube
              videoId={this.state.videodata}
              play={true}
              style={{height: 300, bottom: 20}}
              apiKey={'AIzaSyApUXkjw-mPPX_Ck78Przt5KS93KQkHy6c'}
            />
          )}

it worked